# Jamaa SMPP MessageId

Tags: c#, .net, smpp

Пишу сервис отправки SMS по протоколу SMPP на C#, использую Jamaa SMPP. Раньше не приходилось работать с SMPP, поэтому испытываю существенные затруднения.

Подскажите пожалуйста, каким образом получить `MessageId`? Сообщения генерируются на стороне SQL Server, сервис получает их из базы и отправляет оператору. Требуется менять в базе данных состояние каждого конкретного сообщения: отправлено, доставлено, ошибка и т.д. Для этого необходим `MessageId`, но я не понимаю, как его получить. События, которые генерирует `SmppClient`, не позволяют получить то, что мне нужно.

Comment: Вы на Wiki заходили? Там есть событие `MessageDelivered` -> [Receiving Delivery Notifications](https://github.com/AdhamAwadhi/JamaaSMPP/wiki/Receiving-Delivery-Notifications)

Comment: Заходил, но каким образом с его помощью я могу получить MessageId?